# Extract a Date from a String, String without Space

Tags: c#, .net

string s = "ElectricityBillPayment10/1/21 - 10/31/21";

Extract only date from string

Comment: This depends on a lot of things. Are the strings always laid out like they are here? Will there ever be letters *after* the dates? Will there ever be numbers, `/`s, or `-`s outside the dates? Will the dates always be formatted the same way?

Comment: @NathanWiles, I see where you're going, substring to the right for a fixed length of characters.

Comment: Yes for sure, that's definitely a solution if you always know where the dates are going to be in your string.

Comment: Could you tell me if you need the date as a `DateTime` or simply have it extracted from the original `string` but no need to change the type?

Comment: The string will change, the first date starts with string only. For first date i want to extract date from stringdate combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know the exact format possibilites of your `string` I simply added a `Regex` that searches for all dates in your example formats and extracts them out of the string:

```
string s = "ElectricityBillPayment10/1/21 - 10/31/21";
var regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d+");
var dates = regex.Matches(s).Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Regex ... the 8th wonder of the world ...!

Comment: .Select is not a method for Matches(), Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: @Nav add `using System.Linq` to your code file.